top command working in console but not while using Python subprocess
I want to use specific top command and save the results to file. Using it in console works fine, but when trying the same in python with subprocess it shows an error. I'm using Linux Fedora 41.
Using this command in console outputs results i want, while saving to file:
top -b -n 1000 -d 1 -p `pgrep Discord | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'` > test.txt
but when using it in python program with subprocess:
import subprocess

bashCommand = """ top -b -n 1000 -d 1 -p `pgrep Discord | tr "\\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'` """

print(bashCommand)

with open("test.txt", "w") as outfile:
    proces = subprocess.call(bashCommand, shell=True, stdout=outfile)

it throws:
top: option requires an argument -- 'p'
Why is that and how to fix it?
Process Discord is open, I tried the same with firefox and others to no avail.

Aside: You should learn to use $(command) instead of backticks for command substitution.

The error implies that pgrep isn't finding any processes containing Discord.

You need to check whether there are any Discord processes first, because you can't use the -p option when there are no PIDs.

I'm sure you'd get the same error when running the command by hand in the same condition. It has nothing to do with python.

It's troubling because it finds the procesess normally when i run it by hand and not in python. I tested it with different applications and it works in console just fine.

What do you see if you just change to bashCommand = 'pgrep Discord'?

i think you still need to add an R before the string R"""... to make it raw

@AhmedAEK They escaped the backslash, so it doesn't need to be raw.

No error, but no output to file with bashCommand = 'pgrep Discord', in console it shows like 7 ids

Worked out the issue, flatpak pycharm was running in a sandbox. My bad.

Try a more robust method using Python to achieve your goals. Your syntax is a little problematic, back ticks should be avoided and you had less than ideal syntax. Also there was no error checking or a way to break out of the code gracefully.
A more robust example of using a helper fuction along with a function to monitor Discord. You can also change the process if needed easily to use this for anything.
Updated Code
import subprocess

# Helper function, get all the PIDs
def get_process_pids(process_name):
    # Use pgrep to find all PIDs for the specified process name
    result = subprocess.run(["pgrep", process_name], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    pids = result.stdout.strip().replace("\n", ",")
    return pids if pids else None

# Monitor the prcoess
def monitor_process(process_name):
    pids = get_process_pids(process_name)
    if not pids:
        print(f"No processes found for '{process_name}'.")
        return

    # Run the top command with the specified PIDs
    top_command = ["top", "-b", "-n", "1000", "-d", "1", "-p", pids]
    with open("/tmp/test.txt", "w") as output_file:
        process = subprocess.Popen(top_command, stdout=output_file, text=True)
        try:
            process.communicate()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Monitoring interrupted.")
        finally:
            process.terminate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Set the process name here
    process_name = "Discord"
    monitor_process(process_name)

Explanation
subprocess.Popen: creates a new process to execute a command. Unlike subprocess.run, which waits for the command to complete, Popen allows the command to run asynchronously, meaning the script continues to run and can interact with or monitor the process. HENCE, you can Ctrl + C and end the monitoring on the spot for example.
top_command: This is the command that Popen will execute. In this case, top_command is a list: ["top", "-b", "-n", "1000", "-d", "1", "-p", pids] with all of the desired fields which you've specified.

Thank you for help, the issue was that pycharm installed from flatpak was running in sandbox, sorry for the trouble.
